# Trying to derive the Lorentz factor. Provide no more than a hint

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I'm trying to derive the Lorentz Factor by tackling a simple case of a thought experiment in Special Relativity:

Observer $A$ is situated at a distance $d_A=1cs$ meters to the left of a mirror. Observer $B$ is approaching $A$ from the left at a speed of $c/2$. My goal is to determine the distance $d_B$  (from $B$'s perspective) between $A$ and the mirror.

---

**My attempt:**

Say that when both observers reach the same position, they each shine a ray of light in the direction of the mirror, a ray which both measure to be shot at a velocity of $c$.

$A$'s account of the events is as follows:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{The ray reaches the mirror at} \ t=1s\\
\text{The ray crosses} \ B \  \text{at} \ t=4s/3\\
\text{The ray returns to} \ A \  \text{at} \ t=2s\\
B \ \ \text{reaches the mirror at} \ t=2s
\end{matrix}$$

$B$'s account of the events is as follows:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{The ray reaches the mirror at} \ t=t_\beta \\
\text{The ray crosses} \ B \  \text{at} \ t=t_\beta 3/2 \\
\text{The ray returns to} \ A \  \text{at} \ t=2t_\beta\\
B \ \ \text{reaches the mirror at} \ t=3t_\beta
\end{matrix}$$

Furthermore, we can write $$d_B=\frac{3}{2}ct_\beta$$

Yet at this point I am stuck. In fact, it seems that any value one gives to $t_\beta$ makes all the observations above valid. For example, if we assume $t_\beta=10s$, then according to $B$'s watch the entire trip from $A$ to the mirror took $30s$ and $d_B=15cs$.

---

What am I missing? How could I constrain the value of $t_\beta$ and $d_B$? I would appreciate it if you provide me no more than a hint.

Comment: Nowhwere in your equation you have any relation between t ans tb, or d and db How will you then find a relation between them. Do you know a Minkowski diagram, than draw it and reconsider.